# Can fake air defence radars be built to fool anti radiation missiles?

Tags: military, radar

Running air defence radar can be a dangerous business because of anti radiation missiles like AGM-88. Radar operators learned to switch radar of trying to prevent hits. Missiles were upgraded to counter this. But what prevents to build multiple very cheap fake radar frequency transmitters? If they cost just as a couple of microwave ovens the cost of losing one will be negligible compared to the missile cost and limited availability. Would such a system of fake radars cause interference to the real ones?

Comment: I find this an interesting question, but i don't think it's fundamentally an aviation one

Comment: Agree with @Dan. VTC. And as someone who did ECCM testing 30+ years ago, there's no such thing as a cheap fake radar. It needs to behave like the real radar - power, pulse rate, scan rate - which means it costs as much as the real radar.

Comment: @Gerry a significant part of the cost of a radar is in the receiver and data processor. A radar signal generator + amplifier + antenna that does not need to be coherent with the receiver is still more expensive than a microwave oven, but much cheaper than a real radar.

Comment: @DeltaLima I don't think you could build a credible sim of a targeting radar without a receiver and feedback. The USAF had AD radar sims on their test/training ranges 40 years ago. They weren't cheap. And the purchase price is only a small part of it. Field power, deployment, ops and maintenance, personnel and training all add up. When I retired in the 90's, the trend was toward multiple networked radars to improve survivability and increase performance.